# Sticky Header with Loading Progress bar

Tags: android, progress-bar, lazy-loading, stickyrecycleview

I created a recyclerview using some Sticky header and Databean library.But I want to use Loading Progress bar for refresh the list.I have two Adapters first ItemViewBinder,second HeaderView Binder.And Databean is a list

```
List<ItemListModel> items = result.getItems();
List<HeaderModel> headers = result.getHeaders();
List<DataBean> dataBeans= new ArrayList<>();
```

I added data like this

```
dataBeans.add(new HeaderModel("WEEK 3","31.01-29.01","10h 24m","GOAL","10h"));
dataBeans.add(new ItemListModel("SU","27.01","150",70,1));
```

My problem is how can I add a progress bar to the bottom of the recycler view in my Sticky Header list. Thanks for your advice)

This is my sticky header list
[sticky header list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0spZF.jpg)

and I want to add Progressbar for Load More items

Comment: Okkey I added reference image week numbers are sticky and I want to add a progress bar  bottom of the list for lazy loading.

Comment: I don't have a progressbar,I want to add in recyclerview.I did not create bussines logic with progressbar.